# Beginner help) python invalid syntax

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
i=0
m=0
n=[]
k=0

def GCD(a,b):
    tmp=a%b
    a=b
    b=tmp
    if tmp==0:
        return a
    else:
        GCD(a,b)

while True:
    k=int(input('숫자를 입력하세요 : (0이면 종료)')
    if k != 0:
        i=i+1
        n[i]=k
    else:
        break
for j range(1,i):
    n[j+1]=GCD(n[j],n[j+1])

print(i,'회 최대공약수 =',n[i])
```

I was coding for Euclidean algorithm as a task.
I don't know why there's a syntax error in this part--(if k != 0:)
please help

Comment: missing `)` at end of line `k=int(input('숫자를 입력하세요 : (0이면 종료)')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the preceding line.

```
k=int(input('숫자를 입력하세요 : (0이면 종료)'))
                                             ^
```

Also there's a missing `in` keyword in the `for` loop:

```
for j in range(1,i):
      ^^
```

Comment: oh my god thank you :)